# Replace an imported certificate with AWS Issued

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-certificate-manager

I'm having some trouble understanding how to replace my imported wildcard cert with an AWS Issued one without taking my site offline. Currently I have an imported SSL certificate in ACM. In the DNS I have a record such as:

`*.example.com  A   Simple  - 11.22.33.44`

Which redirects any implicit subdomains at a specific place.

I want to issue a wildcard certificate directly in ACM, but to do that I need to create a CNAME record for `*.example.com`, which apparently is invalid as two records cannot share the same record name.

Is there any way to do this without removing the wildcard DNS record?

Thanks

Comment: In general you can have multiple DNS records for the same name, but you cannot have any other records _with CNAME_ except (metarecords) RRSIG and NSEC*, because such a record's data (like your A) could never be used while the CNAME exists, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record . Why do you think you need a CNAME for `*.example.com`? https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/faqs/ says you need `_TOKEN5.example.com` where TOKEN5 is determined by Amazon, which does not conflict with either `*` or presumably any of your actual subdomain names. But not programming/development.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - thanks, you're absolutely right. I was misreading things - I've added the validation token to the hosted zone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used imported certificates in aws, I directly used certificates issued by AWS (and domains registered in AWS), so maybe I'm wrong.

If I don't remember bad, when you create a certificate in AWS Certificate manager, you choose your domain (mydomain.com), then you add another domain (*.mydomain.com) so all the first level subdomains are covered (and you can add more of them).

Then, in validation method, choose "DNS validation",  and AWS generates a set of CNAME to add to your DNS table in Route53, like these:

| Domain Name | Record Name | Record Type | Record Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mydomain.com | _[32_chars_alphanumeric_string].mydomain.com. | CNAME | _[another_32_chars_alphanumeric_string].asdasdasda.acm-validations.aws. |
| *.mydomain.com | _[32_chars_alphanumeric_string].mydomain.com. | CNAME | _[another_32_chars_alphanumeric_string].asdasdasda.acm-validations.aws. |

At this point you can add them manually to your dns table, or tell aws to do it for you. And you have finished.

In my DNS table I do not need a CNAME with the wildcard for my domain (*.mydomain.com) for the certificate, because I have the records shown above (look at the records names).

I do not know if I have answered your question, I hope this information can be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you - yes it turns out I was misreading the documentation. Adding the CNAME with the values provided by amazon allowed the certificate to be issued. For the sake of clarity for anyone else wondering:

It's safe to add the record to any hosted zone because it's adding a unique name and value. There's no need to remove existing DNS records to validate a new certificate.